# How do I conditionally render 1 of multiple components inside a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically I have four components and I'm trying to render One depending on the state. When I try to do this it doesn't work for some reason. I'm sure there's probably a better way to do this however I've spent hours messing with this and I've yet to figure it out.

```
export default function HelpDiv(){

    const [showDiscordInfo, setShowDiscordInfo] = useState(true);
    const [showRulesInfo, setShowRulesInfo] = useState(false);
    const [showAttendanceInfo, setShowAttendanceInfo] = useState(false);
    const [showServerInfo, setShowServerInfo] = useState(false);

    const handleDiscordInfoClick = () => {
        setShowDiscordInfo(true);
        setShowRulesInfo(false);
        setShowAttendanceInfo(false);
        setShowServerInfo(false);
        
        console.log('1')
        
        }

    const handleRulesInfoClick = () => {
        setShowDiscordInfo(false)
        setShowRulesInfo(true)
        setShowAttendanceInfo(false)
        setShowServerInfo(false)
        console.log('2')
    }

    const handleAttendanceInfoClick = () => {
        setShowDiscordInfo(false);
        setShowRulesInfo(false);
        setShowAttendanceInfo(true);
        setShowServerInfo(false);
        console.log('3')
    }

    const handleServerInfoClick = () => {
        setShowDiscordInfo(false);
        setShowRulesInfo(false);
        setShowAttendanceInfo(false);
        setShowServerInfo(true);
        return(
        console.log('4')
        )
    }


    
        let display 
        if(showDiscordInfo === true){
            display = <HelpDiscord />
        }else if(showRulesInfo === true) {
            display = <HelpRules />
        }else if(showAttendanceInfo === true) {
            display = <HelpDiscord />
        }else if(showServerInfo === true) {
            display = <HelpRules />
        }
    

    return(
        <Wrapper>
            <Navigation>
                <Title>
                    <H3>Info</H3>
                </Title>
                <Icons>
                    <Icon onclick={handleDiscordInfoClick}>
                        <FADiscord />
                        <P>Login</P>
                    </Icon>
                    <Icon onclick={handleRulesInfoClick}>
                        <FAScroll />
                        <P>Rules</P>
                    </Icon>
                    <Icon onclick={handleAttendanceInfoClick}>
                        <FAUserCheck />
                        <P>Attendance</P>
                    </Icon>
                    <Icon onclick={handleServerInfoClick}>
                        <FANetworkWired />
                        <P>Servers</P>
                    </Icon>
                </Icons>
            </Navigation>
            <Info>
                {display}
            </Info>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

also I've done this exact same thing pretty much just with class-based components and gotten it to work as shown below. However, I'm really trying to learn why it doesnt work in the functional component shown above.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

    state ={ 
        showHome: true,
        showForm: false,
        showProjects: false,
        showCv:false,
    }

    handleHomeClick = () => {
        this.setState(({
            showHome: true,
            showProjects:false,
            showForm:false,
            showCv:false,
          })
          );
    }

    handleFormClick = () => {
        this.setState(({
            showForm: true,
            showHome:false,
            showProjects:false,
            showCv:false,
          })
          );
    }

    handleProjectClick = () => {
        this.setState(({
            showProjects: true,
            showHome:false,
            showForm:false,
            showCv:false,
          })
          );
    }

    handleCv = () => {
        this.setState(({
            showProjects: false,
            showHome:false,
            showForm:false,
            showCv:true,
          })
          );
    }

    render() {
        let display
        if(this.state.showForm === true){
            display = <Form />
        }else if(this.state.showHome === true) {
            display = <Home />
        }else if(this.state.showProjects === true) {
            display = <Projects />
        }else if(this.state.showCv === true) {
            display = <Cv />
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? I can't see anything wrong with the code at first glance (not that I would write it this way, but what you have looks like it should work) - but I don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: I've just noticed that you only ever display either `HelpDiscord` or `HelpRules`, ebven though you have 4 conditions (the second two just repeat the first two). Is that the issue?

Comment: So by doesnt work, i'm not getting my console logs back in console after clicking the elements with the onclick. and as far as the HelpDiscord and HelpRules I only put two so that I could see a difference if I did get it to work. I will say when I put parenthesis after the functions inside the onclick onclick={handleDiscordInfoClick()} it tells me that there's too many re-renders in console. Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: No, what you had the first time is definitely correct. That's assuming that the `Icon` component you're using accepts an `onclick` prop that handles the click event - you don't show the definition of that or where you're importing it from. (Perhaps it does accept a handler prop but it's called `onClick` instead? Just guessing though, you need to check that component, or its documentation if it's from a library.)

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU, im an idiot. it was the onClick. sorry this my first time using StackOverflow pretty much. I'm using styled components and did a horrible job showing my work for u guys. Again thank you so much as soon as I read it i was like omg ‍♂️